# NSSplitter how to prevent proportional space distribution on resize

Tags: cocoa, nssplitview

I have a window with a source list sidebar at the right side and a content view on the left both inside an NSSplitView.

When i resize the window, the additional space is distributed to the source list and the content view. How can i make the source list to maintain its fixed width. All Apple applications are doing this so i hope i just missed a method.

Answer (score 5):

On SnowLeopard, there is a delegate method called `splitView:shouldAdjustSizeOfSubview:`. All you have to do is return NO for your source list view, and you should be good. If you need to support Leopard or earlier, you have to implement `splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:` and manually resize the subviews, keeping your source list view a fixed width, and resizing your other view to fill the split view's bounds (taking into account the divider's width).

Both methods are documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSSplitViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Can you do this with autolayout constraints too?